# Dependency between two class

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, decoupling

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {
  Foo foo;
}
```

Since Foo is a type of field of Bar, can we safely claim that Bar depends on Bar? What if foo == None? Does that mean Bar no longer depends on Bar?

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to the difference between composition and aggregation. In the example you have

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {
  Foo foo;
}
```

Here, Bar can exist independent of Foo because foo can be null - a weak dependence.

However, if you had the same relationship defined this way:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {
  Foo foo;
  Bar(Foo foo){
     this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

then, it is a composition relationship, where Bar can not exist without Foo.